# iOS notifications “UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification” also trigger this type of notification when the device is charging

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, development-environment

I needed to use this notification to complete the data refresh, but my iPhone test found that it also triggered the notification when connecting to the charger (or to the computer), causing it to fail to use correctly!

eg:
[[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil] takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeNext:^(NSNotification * _Nullable x) {
NSLog("dosomething");
}];

Comment: Hi uncle - interesting observation you make there, but I suppose you will have to change your data refresh logic a bit. How does this break your data refresh?

Comment: Thank you for your attention and answer, but I wonder, why does it appear when the iPhone connects to the charger trigger that notification?

Comment: A mystery that only Apple will be able to answer ... This is interesting as it is another one of those funny idiosyncrasies that one often encounters with Apple and probably with others as well. I wonder what the history behind this might be - maybe this was some left over notification that Apple used for this purpose or maybe under the hood it is used to check e.g. if the phone can be updated as Apple requires a phone to be connected to the charger before updating. My suggestion is really a pragmatic one - don't worry too much or try to understand too much but just use what you have.